# Something goes wrong with fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I want to fadeOut image, and then do fadeIn with a new one, so I wrote a simple code, but something goes wrong, because when .photo img fadesOut, then fadesIn this same photo, but after, a few second its changes because of new "src", but even if browser didn't load a new image, the old one shound't show, becuase src is changed, but it shows, and after a second, maybe two changes to the new one. Can somebody tell me what's wrong?

```
var dimage = $next.children("img").attr("rel");
$(".photo img").fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $(".photo img").attr("src", dimage);
    $(".photo img").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: you aren't giving the new image enough time to load.

Comment: because it takes a few seconds for the browser to download the image after you change the src.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the image has to load after the src is altered.
Consider putting the image in a tag, then setting the css property to display:none.  This way the image will preload in the browser before your script runs and will be available when it does.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't giving the new image enough time to load.

```
function loadImage (src) {
    return $.Deferred(function(def){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            def.resolve(src);
        }
        img.src = src;
    }).promise();
}
var dimage = $next.children("img").attr("rel");
var imageLoadedDef = loadImage(dimage);
$(".photo img").fadeOut("slow", function () {
    def.done(function(src){
        $(".photo img").attr("src", src);
        $(".photo img").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sure, either fade it in or show it like any other element (but make sure it is preloaded too!)

Answer (score 0):

the problem as highlighted is about images not ready for display when you call them, so the solution is to preload them before starting the slideshow, create a function with an array of images path

```
function preLoad(){
  var imgs = {'test1.jpg', 'test2.jpg', 'test3.jpg'};
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  for(var i = 0; i < imgs.leght; i++){
    img.src = imgs[i]; //all images gets preloaded at this stage
  }

  startSlider(); //here you will do your code
}
```